# Debugging an error message in Firebug

Tags: javascript, firebug

I get this error message in Firebug:

```
Permission denied for <http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net> to call method Location.toString
```

It comes from this page:
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/trees/add_spotted_trees.php?hike_id=108

The login credentials for this page are:
test@comehike.com | password

When I look at it in Firebug, using the Console --> Errors view, I see that error first, followed by a number of other errors, but I can't really double-click on the errors to see what line they are coming from, and the line isn't written there as far as I can see.  There are some line references on the page, but they lead to pretty random spots.

Any ideas how to debug such a thing?  I am new to JS and FireBug.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Location.toString error is usually due to some ad-serving javascript code, trying to get a text version of the current page's location. Firefox denies access to this information to 3rd party scripts by default, since 3rd party scripts should have no business knowing exactly what page you're on.

Basically it's an attempt by ad networks to work around some clients not sending referers, by trying to grab the location data directly.

Comment: I am also getting errors like this: "uncaught exception: [Exception... "'[JavaScript Error: "a.value is null" {file: "chrome://google-toolbar-lib/content/toolbar.js" line: 2655}]' when calling method: [nsIFactory::createInstance]" nsresult: "0x80570021 (NS_ERROR_XPC_JAVASCRIPT_ERROR_WITH_DETAILS)" location: "JS frame :: chrome://google-toolbar/content/gtb.js :: anonymous :: line 82" data: yes]" -- Do you see that on the page?  Any idea why they are there?

Comment: Means something failed to return an object, which should've gotten assigned to 'a', and then some later code tried to access that object without checking if it was one. No idea why it'd be there.

Comment: But the funny thing is that I didn't declare anything as "a" :)

Comment: Looks like it's part of chrome's internal JS stuff.

Answer (score 1):

In firebug under the "bug" icon (upper left when open) you'll see a pause button (in the console tab). This will cause the page to stop loading and jump to the exact error in the script.

However, when I visited the page I do not see any errors.

Answer (score 1):

body' onLoad is:

> initializeTreeHike(  ,  );

You don't need to use comma if you wish to pass no parameters to the function.

Answer (score 1):

When I follow the provided link in Firefox 4.0 with Firebug 1.7, I don't receive the error you encountered. What I do receive however is the following:

Syntax error: initializeTreeHike( , );

It appears this is coming from line 326 in add_spotted_trees.php in the following line:

```
<body onload="initializeTreeHike( , );"
```

Perhaps you meant to pass in empty strings as parameters?